# Why does Google Drive API corrupt my file extension when uploading files through Python?

Tags: python, excel, google-api, google-drive-api

I have created a Python script that pulls files with a .xlsx format from a folder on my computer and uploads the file to a specific folder in my Google Drive. This is using the pydrive package in Python. The script runs with no issues, and the files are uploaded as expected. However, for some reason, when the uploaded Google Drive file is downloaded and re-opened, Excel gives the following error message:

> Excel cannot open the file...because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

When I open the file directly on my computer, it opens fine with no issues. When I manually drag/upload the file into the Google Drive folder, and then re-download the file, it opens with no problem. The transformation seems to be coming from my Python script (see below).

Can anyone provide any help here? I have been trying different things and I keep getting the same result. I can provide more information if necessary.

Updated to add full Python Script:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import glob,os,shutil
import datetime

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

gauth = GoogleAuth()
#gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

# Try to load saved client credentials
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
if gauth.credentials is None:
    # Authenticate if they're not there
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    # Refresh them if expired
    gauth.Refresh()
else:
    # Initialize the saved creds
    gauth.Authorize()
# Save the current credentials to a file
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

#Google Drive Folder ID
fid = '[FOLDER ID PLACEHOLDER]'

#Check to see if today's folder is created on PC
date = datetime.date.today()
today = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

starting_folder = '[FOLDER PLACEHOLDER]'

if not os.path.exists(starting_folder + "/" + today):
    os.makedirs(starting_folder + "/" + today)

destination_folder = starting_folder + "/" + today

#Change directory to the folder where the bulk bid tools are stored
os.chdir("[FOLDER PLACEHOLDER]")

for file in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    try:
        print(file)
        with open(file,"r") as f:
            fn = os.path.basename(f.name)
            file_drive = drive.CreateFile({'parents':[{'kind':"drive#parentReference",'id':fid}],'title':fn})
            file_drive.Upload()
            print("The file: " + fn + " has been uploaded.")
        shutil.move(starting_folder + "/" + fn,destination_folder + "/" + fn)
    except: 
        pass        

print("All files have been uploaded")
```

Comment: Is there a reason you try to open the file for reading? You don't use `f` at all after opening the file. Also, you're using `drive` - can you share the specific installed version of the package and complete your code to include the imports you think are required to make it work?

Comment: Updated the code in my post to help out with that question. `f` is being used to get the base file name. I have the most recent version of pydrive installed. i am still using python 2.7 if that helps as well.

Comment: Writing new Python 2.7 code at this point in time is probably a really bad idea, unless you have some kind of external dependency that absolutely requires it. Instead of opening a file to get its name, consider simply using `Path` from `pathlib` or the appropriate calls to `os.path` functions - you don't need to open a file to get its name, while it may affect what you can do with the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually passing the information of the file to the request. Meaning, you are not really uploading the actual "bytes" of this file to Drive. Just creating an empty drive file with the same name in the determined folder.

If you look at the [documentation for pyDrive](https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/) you can see that after calling of `CreateFile` they use [`SetContentFile`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/pydrive.html#pydrive.files.GoogleDriveFile.SetContentFile).

Copied from the documentation you can see an example like so:

```py
file2 = drive.CreateFile()
file2.SetContentFile('hello.png') # This line needs to be added to your code 
                                  # with the name of the file in your computer
file2.Upload()
# Also check the mimetype afterwards to check the file has been correctly uploaded
print('Created file %s with mimeType %s' % (file2['title'],
file2['mimeType']))
# Created file hello.png with mimeType image/png
```

---

Also from the comments you say you are still running python2 code. Take into consideration that python 2 is "dead" and there will not be more security updates, neither development/support. You should really be considering change as a lot of package and modules are also dropping (or will start to do so) python 2 support.

More information of this issue in [Sunsetting Python 2](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

Comment: Thank you!!! This is the correct answer. I missed the line of code where I needed to `SetContentFile` and that's why my files didn't have any data in them. I really appreciate the help. First SO question a success!